# unable to read name between quotes and parenthesis in java programming using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, url

I have a code and i want to read only the name in the code. The name is inside quotes and parenthesis. I do not care about whole code line but the name only.

**CODE**

```
document.write('john smith') // i just want to read john smith using Regex in java.
```

Actually, i am directly reading through URL. Some of the data i need is in Javascript code and some in other tags and attributes. If i get the solution of this above, i hope, i can handle the rest myself.

Comment: This looks more like JavaScript.

Comment: I'm trying something like `[^(document.write)][^(\")](\\w)[^(\")]`

Comment: I was going to go with this. `\(['"](.*?)['"]\)`

Comment: @Srinivas.. thanks. It was somewhat fine. I just checked it on this website [link](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/). But in my program, Eclipse gives an error message.

Comment: Using regular expressions on strings of javascript code is indicative of an opportunity for a better design.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this will work for you:

```
document\.write\(["']([^"']*)["']\)
```

Which will capture the name as the first capturing group.  That is, when you execute the regex, you should be able to access it as index 1 of your match.  (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regex) for an example using capturing groups).

Although, as a warning, all the [advice against parsing HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) goes double when you throw javascript and the like into the mix.  If your actual application of this is remotely more complex than what you have here, you might want to consider another way to do this.

Comment: Was thinking of escaping in a string, rather than a pattern.  Fixed the escapes.